# Asking for help with hardware fault

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a suspected broken HDD and wondered if there was a Stack Exchange site where I could get an answer to one of the questions I had.

I think Stack Overflow (where I usually post my questions) is not the place to ask but I like Stack Exchange because the answers come in really quickly.

Comment: Either [SU] or [SF]. I'm not sure which is better.

Comment: Mysticial, Super User is for power users, while Server Fault is for professional sysadmins (this means that the typical variant of this question for Server Fault would be "How do I restore it from backup?").

Comment: Please be aware that SU and SF already have *a ton of questions* about failing harddrives...so you most likely will already find answers to your questions. Please don't just ask another "My HDD is dying, how do I rescue the data" question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be [Super User](http://superuser.com), where you can ask question about:

> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking

Super User is not for corporate IT questions, though. If you are a professional sysadmin, you should consider asking on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: I am not sure a question about a broken HDD would be relevant for Server Fault.

Comment: kiamlaluno, we don't know the question so we can only speculate, right? :-) (At least we *didn't* know it before OP posted it to SU).

Comment: I am assuming a HDD is not not directly related to professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration; even a home computer has HDDs. It then depends from the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Quoting the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking